# Concatenated JS/CSS Not Refreshing With Media Stored in DB

Tags: magento-enterprise, aws, ee-1.14.1.0

There seems to be a Magento bug with media stored in DB, FPC and refreshing concatenated JS/CSS files.  Before I dig into the code, I want to see if anyone's already encountered and/or solved this.

I can get it to refresh eventually but I'm not quite sure the combination of clearing cache, removing files manually from file-system on front-end servers and/or deleting rows from 'core_file_storage'.

Otherwise, storing media in DB has been surprisingly painless.  We're deploying to auto-scaling infrastructure (Elastic Beanstalk) and AWS doesn't yet have their shared volume technology ready for EBS at this time.

Many thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this as mentioned here: https://github.com/magento/hackathon_january_2014/pull/29

Magento seems to be working on a fix for this issue. Check with Support.